# Proving a function is not onto

Tags: functions

This is the question from my text book:
Show that $f:\mathbb{R}-\{3\}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\frac{x-2}{x-3}$ is not onto. This is what I have done so far:

$f(x)=y=\frac{x-2}{x-3}\implies x=\frac{3y-2}{y-1}$
For $y=1$, $x$ is undefined.

This means for $y=1$ there is no pre-image $x$ in the domain. Hence, the function is not onto.

I doubt that the function is not onto just because for $y=1$, $x$ is undefined. What have I done wrong and how do I prove that the function is not onto?

Comment: You have done nothing wrong. It is enough if even a single element in the codomain fails to be represented by the function. $1$ is exactly such an element.

Comment: What I mean to say is that, in the question the Domain is said to contain all Real numbers except 3, so I have got to use (which I have not) that information somehow to prove that the function is not onto. So, is the way I have proved, correct?

Comment: The only reason $3$ has been omitted is because the function becomes undefined at this point. You can swap out $\frac{x-2}{x-3}$ for $\frac{x-2}{x-5}$ and swap out $\mathbb R-\{3\}$ for $\mathbb R-\{5\}$- the answer would still be the same.

Comment: I see..so, I guess the way I proved that the function is not onto is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Comment: You're welcome (as an aside, in future, bear in mind that people on stack exchange [generally dislike "thank you" and "you're welcome" comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment) even if it seems like the polite thing to do- but it's not that big of a deal)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to note the same: First
$$f(x)=\frac{x-2}{x-3}=1+\frac{1}{x-3}$$
and since $(x-3)^{-1}$ is always different from zero, then $f(x)\neq 1$ for all $x\neq 3$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no $x$ in the domain that gets mapped to $3$. Therefore, $f$ is not onto.